# Proving d: $Z\ \ \times \ Z\ \rightarrow \ R\ $ to be metric on Z

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The question states: Let $\left(X{,}\ d_1\right)$ and $\left(Y{,}\ d_2\right)$ be two metric space. Let $Z=\ X\times Y\ $. Let $z_{1\ }=\ \left(x_{1\ }{,}\ y_{1\ }\right)$ and $z_{2\ }=\ \left(x_{2\ }{,}\ y_{2\ }\right)\in Z $ and $d: Z\ \ \times \ Z\ \rightarrow \ R\ $ is Defined by $d\left(z_1{,}z_{2\ }\right)=\sqrt{\ d_{1\ }\left(x_{\ 1}{,}\ x_{2\ }\right)^2+\ d_{2\ }\left(y_1{,}\ y_{2\ }\right)^2}$

So we have to show that d is metric on Z

Most of the steps were clear in the book except when proving the triangle inequality part, it was written as

Let $z_{3\ }=\ \left(x_{3\ }{,}\ y_{3\ }\right)$

$$d\left(z_1{,}z_{3\ }\right)=\sqrt{\ d_{1\ }\left(x_{\ 1}{,}\ x_{3\ }\right)^2+\ d_{2\ }\left(y_1{,}\ y_{3\ }\right)^2}$$

$$\le \ \sqrt{\ \left(d_{1\ }\left(x_{\ 1}{,}\ x_{2\ }\right)+d_{1\ }\left(x_{\ 2}{,}\ x_{3\ }\right)\right)^2+\ \left(d_{2\ }\left(y_{\ 1}{,}\ y_{2\ }\right)+d_{2\ }\left(y_{\ 2}{,}\ y_{3\ }\right)\right)^2}$$

Let $\alpha _{1\ }=d_{1\ }\left(x_1{,}\ x_2\right)$, $\beta _{1\ }=d_{1\ }\left(x_2{,}\ x_3\right)$, $\alpha _{2\ }=d_{1\ }\left(y_1{,}\ y_2\right)$, $\beta _{2\ }=d_{1\ }\left(y_2{,}\ y_3\right)$

$$d\left(z_1{,}z_{3\ }\right)\le \ \sqrt{\left(\alpha _{1\ }+\beta _{1\ }\right)^2+\ \left(\alpha _{2\ }+\beta _{2\ }\right)^2}$$
Now this is the part i do not understand, The book states they are using Minkowski's inequality,In the next step they do this,

$$d\left(z_1{,}z_{3\ }\right)\le \ \sqrt{\left(\alpha _{1\ }^2+\alpha _{2\ }^2\right)\ }+\sqrt{\left(\ \beta _{1\ }^2+\beta _{2\ }^2\right)\ }$$

I'm not exactly sure why or how they were able to swap places like that with $\beta _1$ and $\alpha _2$ especially since there is whole bracket square involved, a little elaboration in that, with more steps is really appreciated!!

Please!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "swapping places". This is a direct application of the case of Minkowski's inequality where there are two summands and the exponent is $2$. If you like, think of $v = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ and $w = (\beta_1, \beta_2)$ as points in $\Bbb{R}^2$. This case of Minkowski's inequality is essentially just the triangle inequality for $0$, $v$ and $v + w$: $d(0, v+w) \le d(0, v) + d(v, v+w) = d(0, v) + d(0, w)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Minkowski inequality you need is for the space of real numbers in the special case, where the exponent is 2, so the inequality is
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i+\beta_i)^2\right)^{1/2}\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$

In your case, we have $n=2$, so
$$\sqrt{(\alpha_1+\beta_1)^2 + (\alpha_2+\beta_2)^2}\leq \sqrt{\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2} + \sqrt{\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2}$$

This is the step you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so so so much! god bless!!!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha _i+\beta _i)^2=&\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha _i(\alpha _i+\beta _i)+\sum_{i=1}^n\beta _i(\alpha _i+\beta _i)\\
&\underset{C.S.}{\leq}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha _i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha _i+\beta _i)^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\beta _i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha _i+\beta _i)^2}.
\end{align*}
Dividing both side by $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha _i+\beta _i)^2},$ gives the wished result.